# How can I retrieve secret from Azure Key Vault from my Controller code

Tags: azure-keyvault, defaultazurecredential

I have created an Azure Key Vault which saves my application secrets.

And I want to retrieve the secrets from my Controller code. My controller code is based on  ASP.Net core.

From here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme

I see the example of how to create a `SecretClient`

```
// Create a secret client using the DefaultAzureCredential
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://myvault.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

My question is Since I am running the code on the service side (in Controller side), how can I create DefaultAzureCredential without any interactive authentication?

Comment: Is your controller code deployed to an Azure Web App with a managed identity? If so, note that this section indicates it will use the managed identtity to connect, which is not an interactive authorization method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#defaultazurecredential in fact, you may find you don't need to use keyvault at all, you can manage all authentication via managed identity.

Comment: azure key vault configuration builder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: azure key vault reference in azure app settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: Hi @si Hwang, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***According to [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#defaultazurecredential) referred by you under  [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#defaultazurecredential) , In service side you can use the application with user Managed Identity,`DefaultAzureCredential` will authenticate with that account which is without interactive mode.***

- As the DefaultAzureCredential will read account information via [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#environment-variables) and use it to authenticate.

[image]

```
// When deployed to an azure host, the default azure credential will authenticate the specified user assigned managed identity.

string userAssignedClientId = "<your managed identity client Id>";

var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId });

var blobClient = new BlobClient(new Uri("https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob"), credential);
```

The ***Azure_client_id*** environment variable can be used to set the ***ManagedIdentityClientId*** in addition to setting it via code. When utilising the DefaultAzureCredential, these two approaches are equal. Without having to expose credentials in your code, you may use this identity to log in to any service that accepts Azure AD authentication, including Key Vault.

You can also refer this  [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app) more in detail to use managed identity  to connect Key Vault to an Azure web app in .NET